# Laravel - server error 500 and no way to print error

Tags: laravel, api, rest

I am trying to interact with AlienTech API using `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;` in Laravel.

```
$apiURL = 'https://encodingapi.alientech.to/api/kess3/decode-read-file/user1?callbackURL=https://backend.ecutech.gr/callback/kess3';

        $postInput = [
            'readFile' => public_path('obd1'),
        ];
  
        $headers = [
            'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data',
            'X-Alientech-ReCodAPI-LLC' => $token,
        ];
  
        $response = Http::withHeaders($headers)->post($apiURL, $postInput);

        $statusCode = $response->status();
        $responseBody = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

        dd($responseBody);
```

$responseBody variable is NULL. Error code is 500. How can I see what I am doing wrong. Is there any way to check logs or errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel's HTTP client does not throw exceptions. Try to add

```
$response->throw();
```

after making the request.

You can find many other options to handle errors in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-client#error-handling).

Comment: thanks. I used $e->getMessage(); and it is just showing this. "HTTP request returned status code 500". how can i know details.

Comment: Is `$e` an instance of `Illuminate\Http\Client\RequestException`? Then it will have a `$response` property. Does that show anything?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a local server, than if you turn on the debug option you are able to see the specific error with details in the laravel.log file. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/errors